# Create irregularly shaped gaps in cube

Tags: modeling, texturing, topology

I need to create a cross section of a surface (which takes the form of a cube), and therefore there are certain areas which need to be "empty". A visual description of what it would look like is below:[image: Cross section with gaps].

Moreover, it might be necessary to include that there is a particle system that is emitted from the surface, and these particles should not be emitted from "empty area".

### **Things I have tried:**

- The cell fracture add-on... to not much success. Not sure if I am using it incorrectly.
- Simply deselecting 50-80% of the faces (I subdivided the cube already) and then deleting them.

None of these methods create an optimal output. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is what I have so far:
[image]

The yellow portion is to be modeled like the green cross-section provided before. As you can see, the small black-white bits on top of the yellow is a particle system that is frozen to 1 frame. So, tying everything together, I'm trying to model yellow area to look like the green image shown earlier, however the particle system must **only** emit from the non-empty areas.

Comment: Do you need actual geometry (as in this will be 3D printed) or can you live with a solution using textures?

Comment: It is not very clear what you already have and what you still need to achieve, could you please clarify? Do you have the green shape modeled already and wish to make a cross section of it? Do you have a particle system that produces that shape or is the particle system supposed to be emitted from the green mesh?

Comment: @cegaton No I do not need actual geometry, a solution with textures is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have edited the question with the information you need!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I'm still not sure what you need exactly, how it differs from what you already got or why yours is not satisfactory, but here is what I came up with.

[image]

Just add a simple cube to your scene, and a small *Metaball*. Adjust the Meta Ball size as desired, but make sure you apply the scale and adjust precision correspondingly afterwards.

Now add a particle system set to *Volume* to the Cube object, and under *Render* as particle object add to it the Metaball. Adjust the number of particles as necessary. A high number is expected, and so is the corresponding slowness and unresponsiveness, just give it a little.

Make the particle system emitter invisible (make the cube draw as Wire only so you can see what you are doing too), and tick *Unborn* and *Died*, also turn off physics.

Once happy with the settings select the **original metaball** (not the cube or particle system) and convert it to a mesh. Manually erase the stray original metaball, then you can add a *Boolean* modifier to it, and intersect with the original cube mesh.

[image]

To keep distinct materials at the intersection faces just add a second material slot to the object with the *Boolean* modifier before applying it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed for the background portion of the cube. I still need there to be some black/white striped particles on top of the portions of the cube that are whole. i.e, the parts that are **not** deformed inwards. Is there a way to do this from here?

Comment: Boolean modifier should keep materials by default, just add a second material slot to the object with the desired material for the intersections. Answer updated

Comment: Is there a way to emit particles from the yellow portion of the cube? I tried adding a particle system on the Mball, but that did not work.

Comment: If you have any further questions please ask them separately in a new post, comments are not for extended discussions. Be sure to search before asking I'm sure you'll find many relevant answers

Comment: You've made a  [chocolate crackle](https://www.kelloggs.com.au/en_AU/recipes/chocolate-crackles.html)

Comment: Haha the resemblance is uncanny. Well this just tunes really well with my newfound fascination for food renderings. Might also make for a nice ground beef or burger patty