# How do you use the Boolean Modifier on an Ocean Modifier to cut a cube in half and apply a material to the bottom half only

Tags: modifiers

I would like to create a cross section of a patch of ocean (animated surface at the top, terrain at the bottom and water in-between), the starting point is to create this...

[image]

... how can this be done in Blender 2.8?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube/84845#84845

Answer (score 0):

With a boolean you can use difference as your boolean and select the ocean object.