# How do i start making this character?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I need some help, tried making this character...started off by using meta ball, then tried subdividing a cuboid and what not....i want help with how to get the base mesh ready

Comment: Like always: Sculpting -> Retopo -> Baking -> Shading.

Comment: this is a 2D character, how would you him to look like in 3D? maybe give some references. Maybe particles could be useful for the face part...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends what style do you wanna use? cartoon or real? high poly vs low poly?
here some references you should check (see the wireframe view to check how they model a similar mesh):

- https://www.turbosquid.com/it/3d-models/3d-shake-nigiri-1401254
- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/handpainted-nigiri-sushi-combo-f3cd020bdad449b89afe9d21ed6fccc6
- https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/food/miscellaneous/sushi-toro (metaballs for rice)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hey! thanks for those! just about what i required

Comment: great to know: please upvote and choose as approved answer :D