# How to create a bumpy rubber material?

Tags: materials, shaders

I am trying to create a decent approximation of the bumpy rubber material depicted in the reference image below. I'm not intimately familiar with nodes, but I figure this is the best route? Ultimately I would like for this to work in both Eevee and Cycles, but if we can only figure out Cycles, I can live with that.

I tried [metaballs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/index.html) at first, but it seemed unnecessarily time intensive and wasn't yielding the results I was looking for, granted that could just be my ignorance.

[image: WIP]

[image: Reference]

[image: Material WIP]

Comment: I remember there was a tutorial for polka dots, if you used those and added them to the bump as the tiny dots that might work

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube/84845#84845

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this. I used a [Voronoi texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html) clamped with a [Color Ramp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html), similar to what you did to make the main dots. I then used another *Voronoi Texture*, scaled up slightly, and clamped differently with another *Color Ramp* to get the smaller dots. I also mixed the input vectors of both the large and the small dots with  a Noise Texture to make them less perfectly round.

Lastly, I mixed the whole thing with another (largely scaled up) [Noise Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html) to give the fine "grain". I also gave a very small subsurface value to emulate that semi-translucent rubber look.

[image: Dots2]

Comment: Thanks for the graph breakdown. I was able to achieve fairly good results with it, though rather than shearing off the tips, I dialed back the color ramps to give them a little more roundness.

Answer (score 5):

Create a basic shape ...

[image]

Add **Remesh** modifier to get even grid, than add **Displace** modifier with **Voronoi** texture to get bubble structure... and Apply modifiers

[image]

Switch to **Sculpt** mode > *Filtr* brush > **Inflate** that is essential for final shape.

[image]

Than use **Scrape** brush to flatten highest vertices as much as you want ...

[image]

As final touch for the "melty/glued" look, use *Remesh modifier > Voxel >* 0.2 again.

[image]

If you want to make mesh lighter, you can bake a Normal map of this mesh to base (original lowpoly) mesh and use *Subdivision* modifier with *Adaptive* enabled.

Comment: Even though this project ended over a year ago, it's great to see a few additional methods I had never considered. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

*Just for fun ... I wanted to try more physically based technique, but cloth sim is quite calculation intensive, means also time consuming ... and result needs sculpt polishing as well.*

---

### Cloth Simulation

Add particle system to base object *Emission > Volume > Grid* with some *Randomness*

[image]

- Use *Icosphere* to be *Rendered* as particles with some *Scale* randomness
- *Make Instances Real* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and *Join* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> them into one object.
- enable *Cloth* simulation > *Pressure* > 0.5 and *Self Collision*
- for original base object enable *Collision* in *Physics Properties* and invert Normals <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> *Inside*
- add two scale keyframes to animate downscale

[image]

Animated result already use *Solidify* modifier to fill spaces produced *Collision Distance* value, *Smooth* modifier because smashed lowpoly *Icospheres* were quite collapsed ... and *Remesh* modifier.

Also here seems like a bit of *Sculpt > Filter > Inflation* helped looks better ... so at the end method with *Displace* seems to be faster with almost the same result.

[image]

Comment: so maybe you should answer this similar question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219183/expanding-baloon-like-softbody-object-how-to-do-in-blender-easy-in-cinema4d

Answer (score 2):

You could create a plane, switch to *Sculpt* mode, enable the *Dyntopo* option (with a low enough *Detail Size*), and paint with the *Blob* brush. Then if you want you can bake the normals and use the result as a *Normal Map* for a low-poly surface:

[image]

Comment: I haven't really explored sculpting in Blender yet, though it seems this particular mesh would benefit from doing so. Thanks for suggesting it!