# Expanding Balloons

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I've seen a lot of motion graphics animations from Cinema4D - expanding balloons compressed into a shape.
The most recent one is the animation from **[Mi Fans 2021](https://www.instagram.com/p/CNctrJfHwQ5/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link)**

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

1. First thing I tried is using a *Cloth* simulation instead of *Softbody*, thinking it will expand by using the pressure settings.
2. I tried *Softbody*, but because the object cant expand on its own, I added a *Force Field* inside, and here's what happened.

[image]

It works for some, but as you can see, as the "balloon" expands it leaves the force field so now the force field is pushing the object to a corner.

Right now I'm still finding the best way to do it in Blender, I've researched some c4D tutorials to get the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Related - but quite an old answer so there may be a better way. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82997/29586

Answer (score 7):

*Cloth Simulation* > **Presure** seems to be working in some way ... just a quick test. You already noticed presure is not expand sphere shapes and Cloth object Scale transformation is not taken into account during simulation. So what I did here instead of expanding bubbles I scaled down collision object (Cube).

[image]

[image]

@RichSedman [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82997/29586) should work ... seems to be more stable and is using "expanding" ballons ... that is what you asked for.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I've been refining my original solution and think I've improved it somewhat... it might take me a while to write it up as an answer though. I'll add it when I can.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/CNctrJfHwQ5/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link
in the link I attached, the baloon is the one that expands, not the cube that shrinks,
but i guess i'll try to play more with the cloth simulation

Comment: I know .. and for that I mentioned that ... and that is why I mentioned also Rich's answer that does what you asked expanding SoftBody bubbles. So use that one :)

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: What do you mean specifically? :) This thread reminds me the [geo-nodes test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5eGxPoqfvA)