# How to achieve soft body pieces squeezed inside of sphere effect like this?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I want to create something similar to this ad at around 4 seconds in: https://www.themill.com/work/case-study/samsung-notebook-plus2/

[image]

You see these balloon-like objects that seem to be squeezed into a cube, like a mime. Then it's as though a boolean occurs.

I want to create something similar but with a sphere, and where the actual sphere is not visible, just the objects that are squeezed inside of it, like the ad.

I also want to replicate the boolean effect.

I've never tried soft body stuff or physics stuff before, and am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: maybe look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object-inflated-balloons-in-a-box

Comment: Thank you! I tried this with a sphere and it seems to have worked only after adding collision to the sphere and flipping the normals, as well as adding collision to every bubble. However, when I try to do a boolean of a cube into the collision sphere (not the bubbles), they don't get squeezed, they pass right through the boolean as though there is no cube. Even if I add collision to the cube, it still doesn't work.

Comment: do you really have to use a boolean, can't you use an invisible object as a collision object?

Comment: True! I just tried and it worked! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: alternative https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219183/expanding-balloons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basic balloon trick, see the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object-inflated-balloons-in-a-box). Then, instead of using *Boolean*, use an invisible object and give it *Collision*.

Comment: Do you know how I could prevent it from inflating over time just having it remain at a constant level of inflation?

Comment: maybe stop the simulation at a given frame (under Cache)?

Comment: Well I do want to animate the balls as they move around, so I think I want to keep the simulation going to maintain that soft bouncing effect. Would this maintain that?

Comment: oh ok, I don't know enough about soft bodies, I hope someone will tell