# How do you make styrofoam?

Tags: materials

I'm having trouble creating a bump for a styrofoam material. I tried using a voronoi texture, but if you use crackle, the edges are too sharp and using f1 results in a sharp point in the middle (almost like a mountain).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create porous material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/how-to-create-porous-material)

Comment: @sairaajm. Would be better if you can add some reference image to let us see what result are you looking for and result you end up for now.

Comment: Or why not check this [web page](https://blenderartists.org/t/styrofoam-texture/1162967/4) where you can get a similar result using coloramp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me you are looking for a way to clamp *Voronoi* texture, so try **Map Rang**e or **Colorramp** node.

[image]

Comment: Sooo Simple! :)

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm, but its far from something realistic https://www.123rf.com/photo_25870121_abstract-white-background.html, Voronoi just cant handle this kind of pattern, that is why I previously tried this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218234/2214 ... also there is many more visual representation of this material - surface from form, when cut, when broken ... sometimes particles are with holes sometimes totally expanded into compact ...  on some of the images it looks like Voronoi>Distance from edge ... other aspects - translucency or sss ...

Comment: Hmm. Voronoi gives you position of feature-point, and max radius in cell. I wonder what would happen if you vector-displaced towards position, until you hit max radius? Or suchlike?

Answer (score 3):

Some styrofoam has little to no space between the beads (cups for example), instead it's like the cracks between them have squeezed out just slightly.

For this I've multiplied a *Voronoi Texture* by itself, and then used a very small *Distance* value for the *Bump* node.

[image]

Comment: Also, doing a little research I found that Styrofoam is a brand name, and this is polystyrene.