# Fitnessbar texture

Tags: texturing, displacement

I have to create a texture similar to this bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGTN.jpg][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGTN.jpg)
or this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Maz5.jpg][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Maz5.jpg) but i can't create something like that with the displace because i have some problems in skretching the textures on the short sides [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7HK9.jpg]
someone have an idea? thanks

i tried with geometry as you suggested but it doesn't work :(https://i.stack.imgur.com/23SBj.jpg][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23SBj.jpg)

Comment: Could this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrYrKBAS70Y tutorial help you with the outer material setup?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube/

Answer (score 1):

### Scaling the Normals

Use the Scale node with the Normal attribute and multiply by the bump texture.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, thank you!, could you send me your blend file please so i can see better? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not save :/ . https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDtHC.png Bigger image of the node tree.