# rise cookie with shaders?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

Is possible to create a shader like this rise cookie? I can notice that some areas have holes but some other looks like bumps at the same time? using bump and displacement at the same time with a displacement modifier for the holes? not only that but to make some parts coloured? like this example? some advice? thanks in advance!

[image: cookie itself]

Comment: Do you mean **Rice** cookie? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube

Comment: thanks Duarte! this is exactly what I required :D thanks!